# is it possible to get mipmap image by id?

Tags: java, android, mipmaps

I have stored image icons in res/mipmap folder of my android project. Each of them have their own image id. I want to check if I have image there by image id. I want to do something like,

```
String input_id = "blue_image";
ImageView image;
if (image.getImageByID(input_id)){  ## if image with blue_image exists
    image.setImageResource(...);
}
```

If I know that blue_image exists then I usually get it like

```
image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.blue_image);
```

There seems to be 2 problems in this question. One is about checking image exists by ID and second one is to find something similar to `getattr()` python function in java.

If you have any other solutions to similar case, those are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your Activity class:

```
int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(inputId, "drawable", getPackageName());

if (imageId > 0) {
    image.setImageResource(imageId);
}
```

The point is that `getIdentifier()` returns `0` if no resouce was found.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(inputId, "mipmap", getPackageName());
```

With "mimap", not "drawable" as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911675/4669135) suggests